# how to setup a bridge with 2 NICs and few virtual machines

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, virtualbox, bridge

Here is my situation.
I have a server with 2 NICs.
I have installed virtual box  and I have created a few Guest Operating Systems on it.
I want these Virtual Machines to be using a bridge.NIC2 would be used to setup this bridge and NIC1 would be connected to corporate network.I am not clear with how should I go on doing this.
`/etc/network/interfaces` is the file
which I am trying to modify etc.
My approach is following

1) Define a configuration file /etc/network/interfaces
2) Create IPTABLES as how NIC1 will forward the packets to Bridge on NIC2

Now comes the problem I do not understand what is the meaning of following lines in the configuration file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
       address 192.168.1.14
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       network 192.168.1.0
       broadcast 192.168.1.255
       gateway 192.168.1.10
       # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
       dns-nameservers 192.168.13.2
       dns-search myserver.net
       bridge_ports eth2
       bridge_fd 9
       bridge_hello 2
       bridge_maxage 12
       bridge_stp off
```

So any pointers to what should be the entries of /etc/network/interfaces file.
So that I understand which parameter is to be used when and where that would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bridge_ports eth2
```

That's the key line, you should add your interfaces, virtual and otherwise, that you want to be a member of the bridge.

```
bridge_ports eth0 eth2
```

The rest of that just describes the options for the bridge. For further reading, the manpage on `brctl` will give you descriptions of the options.

Additionally, to dynamically add and remove ports to the bridge once they're created, just use brctl to do it.

```
brctl addif br0 eth3
brctl delif br0 eth3
```

To get a list of ports already in the bridge

```
brctl br0 show
```

Comment: Oh I see I did not knew about bridge_ports option thanks for that I checked out the corresponding man pages here 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man5/bridge-utils-interfaces.5.html
and 
http://man-wiki.net/index.php/5:ifcfg-bridge 


 </br>
How ever as my understanding is when we have a bridge then we need to give an IP to the bridge and I want to give an IP to NIC1,so what will be corresponding entry for that?So if I give an IP to the NIC1 and an IP to bridge would that be correct?What I understand bridge just works on frames nothing else.